# only show first n checkboxes/elements in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a website and I have a search form with some options. You can view it here: https://www.travelstuff.be/search/. Because it's in Dutch, I will guide you through.

When you look at the left side of the page, you see 2 lists with blue squares ('Type' en 'Merk' ('Merk' is dutch for 'Brand').

The problem is with the 'Merk'-list. It will get quite long. For now, only 12 checkboxes are shown, but when I add more brands, the list will get longer (obviously).

I want to create a little snippet in JavaScript, that only shows the first 5 (or 10) checkboxes + a button below. When the button is clicked on, all the checkboxes are shown.

I use Twig to render the layout, and it renders it like this:

```
<div class="filter">
    <div class="title">Merk</div>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="..." class="..." />...</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="..." class="..." />...</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="..." class="..." />...</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="..." class="..." />...</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" name="..." class="..." />...</label>
    ...
</div>
```

It's technically impossible to wrap the first 5 labels in another div (due to the limitations of Twig). Is there another way to do this? I really have no clue how to search for a problem like this, I think a solution is on here somewhere, but I have no idea where to look for it. English is not my native language.

Thanks in advance!

### Edit

This is my 'solution'.

```
$('.filter').each(function(){
    var self = $(this);
    var labels = self.find('label');
    var labelsSelected = self.find('label[data-selected="true"]').length;
    if(labelsSelected == 0){
        self.find('label:gt(4)').hide();
        var $a = $('<a href="#" />').html('Meer').appendTo(self);
        $a.on('click', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            self.find('label').show();
            $(this).remove();
        });
    };
});
```

First of all, I loop over each filter. I get all the labels in it, and I check if any checkboxes are selected. If so, all the labels must be shown. If not, only the 5 first labels must be shown.

Comment: How about setting the display property of the n last elements or n first elements with a class and just removing the class by clicking on +?

Comment: You can use `.filter label:nth-of-type(n+6)` to select labels #6 to last.

Comment: @Chris G I think that's a possible solution, yes. I'll try it.